# Changing background with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background of my element depending on screen width. However, I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have in my css file:

```
.landscape {
    background-image:url(../images/thumb-1920-559128.jpg);
    min-height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;}
```

And this is in my script.

```
if (container_width>mobSwitch)  {
    bg.attr("class","landscape");}
```

When my css only had `fill: #333333;` it worked fine. Now it's just starting to piss me off. Please help.

I've pushed it up to git. https://github.com/faizaakhtar/interactive

Look at the iframe.html

Comment: Could you add a JSfiddle or whatever with a "working" example of your problem.

Comment: From your code, I can see a punch of undefined variables.

Comment: What is `bg`? If that is the element on which background is to be changed then you have to do `bg.setAttribute("class", "landscape");`

Comment: In the script, I left out all the other stuff that is working, bg is defined. like so, `var bg=graph.append("rect").attr("width","100%").attr("height","100%");`

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this without using JavaScript, using CSS media queries.

HTML:

```
<div class="landscape">
  <!-- Your DIV content here. -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) { // Assuming mobWidth = 480px
   .landscape {
       background-image: url('../images/thumb-1920-559128.jpg');
       // Other styles.
   }
}

.landscape {
    background-image: none // Or an image.
    // Other styles.
}
```

Comment: That would be great, but I'm trying to build an interactive infographic that someone else is going to embed on their page as an iframe. Does that matter? I don't really know front end. I'm just giving it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage = "url('yourimage.jpg')";,

And replace with your image URls

```js
document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage = "url('yourimage.jpg')";
```

```css
.landscape {
    background-image:url(../images/thumb-1920-559128.jpg);
    min-height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div class="landscape" id="test">Hello test</div>
```